# Facebook login error in android : There is error in logging you in the application

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: Facebook login error]

I am getting the following error in signed apk. I updated all key hashes from play store or from keytool  bit still same error

Comment: Verify key hashes of your signed APK SHA & update on Facebook developer console if required

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed I updated key hashes in the release mode but still same

Comment: try to remove all key hashes and add again. Check if it works

Comment: same issue after removing all and then adding them.  I am getting this issue only in the case of Facebook app . If I set lgoin behaviour as web then it is working fine